# Display none if URL parameter is empty

Tags: javascript, php, function, shortcode

Here is the URL where I'm getting the first name. Ideally, if we have a value in the parameter it shows the name e.g  James, and if a null value for this parameter, on the front end we shouldn't see |FIRST_NAME|.

[https://google.com/pfn=|FIRST_NAME|](https://google.com/pfn=%7CFIRST_NAME%7C)

Here is the code for getting that response.
`

```
    function pfn_shortcode() { 
    $thefirstname = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {
        $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
    }

    echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome
 <span>$thefirstname</span></p>" ;
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('first_name', 'pfn_shortcode');
```

`

[image]

I'm looking for a way to hide null responses on the front-end using PHP functions.

Comment: Where does `FIRST_NAME` show up in the code you're showing? It doesn't seem to come from anywhere.

Comment: function pfn_shortcode() { 
    $thefirstname = "";
    if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {
        $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
    }

    echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome 
 <span style='color: #000000;'>$thefirstname</span></p>" ;
} 
// register shortcode
add_shortcode('first_name', 'pfn_shortcode');


In my mistake, I attached the image code for the first name incorrectly. Please see the code attached above for the first name

Comment: move `echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome
 <span>$thefirstname</span></p>" ;` into your `if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {`

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I did that but it's not working. 
'if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {
   $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];

   echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome to xiQ
   <span style='color: #000000;'>$thefirstname</span></p>" ;

  }'

Comment: Here is the solution.

    `function pfn_shortcode() { 
        $thefirstname = "";
        if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {
            $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
        }

        if($thefirstname == '|FIRST_NAME|') echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome 
        </p>";
        else echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome 
            <span style='color: #000000;'>$thefirstname</span></p>";
    } 
    // Register Shortcode
    add_shortcode('first_name', 'pfn_shortcode');`

Answer (score 0):

In your `pfn_shortcode()`, whatever value you passed as GET param `pfn` will be taken as the `$thefirstname`.

If your URL is like `https://google.com/pfn=|FIRST_NAME|`, $thefirstname will be **|FIRST_NAME|**

If you build these URLs dynamically, and replace the **|FIRST_NAME|** placeholder with code, for some reasons some URLs are not getting replaced.
In that case,

add an extra condition to your `pfn_shortcode()` as

```
if (isset($_GET['pfn']) && $_GET['pfn'] !== '|FIRST_NAME|') {
    $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
}
```

OR

if your URLs are generated manually, avoid `pfn` param from the URL

Comment: URLs are generated dynamically.

Comment: Here is the solution.

    `function pfn_shortcode() { 
        $thefirstname = "";
        if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {
            $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
        }

        if($thefirstname == '|FIRST_NAME|') echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome 
        </p>";
        else echo "<p class='firstname'>Welcome 
            <span style='color: #000000;'>$thefirstname</span></p>";
    } 
    // Register Shortcode
    add_shortcode('first_name', 'pfn_shortcode');`

Comment: I don't see any major difference in this. You wrote a few more extra lines to omit a <span> from the whole page.

Comment: With the else statement, I've dealt with what I want to show. Within else, I have echo a message with a parameter, and within IF, I have echo a welcome

Comment: Yeah! But if you replace the `if ( isset( $_GET['pfn'] ) ) {
        $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
    }` in your code with the `if (isset($_GET['pfn']) && $_GET['pfn'] !== '|FIRST_NAME|') {
    $thefirstname = $_GET['pfn'];
}` as in my answer, you will get the same result.